# Set two buttons on each cell with different action but same frame

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I need to set two buttons on each cell with different actions but same frame, on click one will hide other will visible. How can i do this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can make use of `insertSubview:aboveSubview:` and `insertSubview:belowSubview:`upon action method call.

Comment: In action of the visible button, add

      `topButton.enabled=NO;`

Comment: Isn't it possible with something like buttons hidden property and tags.

Comment: @Unknown that i tried already but the question is how to tag different actions for each button of cell, and button must be identified it is called from which cell.

Comment: set `indexPath.row` to the tag value of button, on tap action u can identify which row was tapped..

Comment: what do you want to do in your button action???

Comment: a checked button is there when it is clicked the button will become unchecked and the status of that particular cell will be changed in databse and it will show unchecked until checked again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell * cell = 
    [tableHistory dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: SimpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle    reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    else
    {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(270.0, 7.0, 30.0, 30.0)];

    if([[arrayCheckUnchek objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"check"])

        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"right-with-bg.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    else
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick-bg.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [button addTarget:self   action:@selector(buttonClicked:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:button];


    cell.textLabel.text = [cellDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [arrayTktcode objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    [cell addSubview:btnUnScan];

    [cell addSubview:btnUScan];

    return cell;

}

-(void)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{

    CGPoint touchPoint = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:tableHistory];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableHistory indexPathForRowAtPoint:touchPoint];

    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

    if([[arrayCheckUnchek objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Uncheck"])
    {
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"right-with-bg.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [arrayCheckUnchek replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"check"];
    }
    else
    {
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick-bg.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [arrayCheckUnchek replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"Uncheck"];
    }
}
```